# RavenDB installation problems System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (10013)

Tags: powershell, installation, ravendb, socketexception

I am trying to install RavenDB. O downloades all the installation files from https://ravendb.net/download. The readme file states the following:

> ## Startup instructions for RavenDB on Windows
>
> - RavenDB as a Console Application Open Powershell Type:
>   .\run.ps1
> - RavenDB as Service Open Powershell Type:
>   .\setup-as-service.ps1
>
> The above command is going to install 'RavenDB' service on your
> machine. Note it requires to be run as administrator. It is going to
> ask whether you'd like to setup secure RavenDB server. The server is
> going to start on port 8080 or 443, if you have chosen to run in
> secure mode.
>
> You can view its status using the Get-Service Powershell cmdlet:
>
> > Get-Service -Name RavenDB
>
> Status   Name               DisplayName
> ------   ----               ----------- Running  RavenDB            RavenDB
>
> To manage service you can use Stop-Service and Start-Service cmdlets
> (requires administrator privileges).
>
> - Setup Open browser, if not opened automatically, at url printed in "Server available on: " Follow the web setup instructions at:
>   https://ravendb.net/docs/article-page/5.0/csharp/start/installation/setup-wizard
> - Upgrading to a New Version Follow the upgrade instructions available at:
>   https://ravendb.net/docs/article-page/5.0/csharp/start/installation/upgrading-to-new-version

So I did the first step: I opened the PowerShell as administrator, I navigated to the location of the run file and I executed it. What I obtain is the following:

> ```
>    _____                       _____  ____
>   |  __ \                     |  __ \|  _ \
>   | |__) |__ ___   _____ _ __ | |  | | |_) |
>   |  _  // _` \ \ / / _ \ '_ \| |  | |  _ <
>   | | \ \ (_| |\ V /  __/ | | | |__| | |_) |
>   |_|  \_\__,_| \_/ \___|_| |_|_____/|____/
>
>
>   Safe by default, optimized for efficiency
> ```
>
> Build 52012, Version 5.2, SemVer 5.2.3, Commit 999bd2d  PID 12744, 64
> bits, 4 Cores, Phys Mem 7.884 GBytes, Arch: X64  Source Code (git
> repo): https://github.com/ravendb/ravendb  Built with love by
> Hibernating Rhinos and awesome contributors!
> +---------------------------------------------------------------+
>
> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (10013): Intento de acceso a un
> socket no permitido por sus permisos de acceso.    at
> System.Net.Sockets.Socket.UpdateStatusAfterSocketErrorAndThrowException(SocketError
> error, String callerName)    at
> System.Net.Sockets.Socket.DoBind(EndPoint endPointSnapshot,
> SocketAddress socketAddress)    at
> System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Bind(EndPoint localEP)    at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Transport.Sockets.SocketConnectionListener.g__BindSocket|13_0(<>c__DisplayClass13_0&
> )    at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Transport.Sockets.SocketConnectionListener.Bind()
> at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Transport.Sockets.SocketTransportFactory.BindAsync(EndPoint
> endpoint, CancellationToken cancellationToken)    at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Infrastructure.TransportManager.BindAsync(EndPoint
> endPoint, ConnectionDelegate connectionDelegate, EndpointConfig
> endpointConfig)    at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.KestrelServerImpl.<>c__DisplayClass29_0`1.<<StartAsync>g__OnBind|0>d.MoveNext() --- End of stack trace from previous location ---    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.AddressBinder.BindEndpointAsync(ListenOptions endpoint, AddressBindContext context)    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.ListenOptions.BindAsync(AddressBindContext context)    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.AddressBinder.AddressesStrategy.BindAsync(AddressBindContext context)    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.AddressBinder.BindAsync(IEnumerable`1
> listenOptions, AddressBindContext context)    at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.KestrelServerImpl.BindAsync(CancellationToken
> cancellationToken)    at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.KestrelServerImpl.StartAsync[TContext](IHttpApplication`1
> application, CancellationToken cancellationToken)    at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.WebHost.StartAsync(CancellationToken
> cancellationToken)    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.WebHost.Start()
> at Raven.Server.RavenServer.Initialize() in
> C:\Builds\RavenDB-Stable-5.2\52012\src\Raven.Server\RavenServer.cs:line
> 249    at Raven.Server.Program.Main(String[] args) in
> C:\Builds\RavenDB-Stable-5.2\52012\src\Raven.Server\Program.cs:line
> 180 Press enter to continue...:

Does anyone have any idea of why is this hapening? I have really spent a lot of time looking for answers on the internet like allowing the exe files to go through the Windows firewalls, activating ports manually, etc...and now I jsut don't know what to try.

Thnak you for your answers.

Answer (score 3):

The issue is likely that you have some other service that is also listening on the port that RavenDB is trying to use.

You can check what port it is by looking at the `settings.json` file, see the value for `ServerUrl` and `ServerUrl.Tcp`.

Usually, RavenDB will try to bind to port `38888` and `8080`. If you have something else already listening to those ports, you'll have an error.